# Getting correct OpenCL version installed on Intel

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

I want to play red eclipse and it requires OpenCL 2.0 at least. But my system has version 1.4 installed As this command `glxinfo | grep -i OpenCL`shows:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G33 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS
My PC specs are:

- Intel Core 2 Duo E4500 CPU
- 2GB DDR2 RAM

I have seen different methods to upgrade the driver but I don't know whether the newer versions are compatible with my system or not. How do I know which is the suitable version for my system? How do I install it?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Intel article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html) your graphics card supports OpenGL 1.4 on the hardware level.

You can try to force OpenGL version with something like:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3COMPAT game-name
```

but it may not work.

References:

- https://steamcommunity.com/app/262410/discussions/0/458605613414324092/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Overriding_reported_OpenGL_version